# Error running headless Chromium on Ubuntu

Tags: chromium

I installed Chromium 59.0, and I'm trying to run it in headless mode using the following command:

`sudo /opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox`

but I'm getting the following errors:

`[0512/174717.638937:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(295)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
[0512/174717.639027:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(254)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected`

Has anyone encountered this and found a way to get past it?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same thing under dockerized ubuntu running karma.js tests.

You will need to have pulseaudio or similar running.

Try:

```
apt-get install pulseaudio
```

And before you run chrome

```
pulseaudio --daemonize
```

You can see it in my docker-entrypoint.sh: 
https://github.com/codeclou/docker-nodejs-chrome-xvfb

When running with docker you will need to run docker with:

```
--shm-size=128M
```

Since chrome will complain about small /dev/shm which is 64MB by default.